# Adding a "Sign In/My Account" link to an external app

Tags: authentication

I'm using (or I'm going to use) WordPress for my product's marketing site. I use Rails for the product's application.

Right now on my marketing site, which is currently in Rails, I have a link that reads either "My Account" or "Sign In" depending on whether you're signed in or not.

I'd like to duplicate this feature on my WP site but I of course won't have the privilege of doing it in as direct a way as I am on my Rails marketing site now.

I'm thinking I'll want to keep track via a cookie whether the user is logged in, which I assume is possible because the application and marketing site will both be on the same TLD.

What's not clear to me is what would be a good way to read that cookie in WP. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can read cookies both on the front- and back-end sides.

For the front-end, you have to provide both links, and show only the desired one with javascript. Use `document.cookie.indexOf('cookie_name')` to check the cookie presence.

For the back-end, you can read the [special `$_COOKIE` variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) to check the cookie presence in you template and change the link with this information.

The fact the your PHP application is inside Wordpress will not make much difference.